# Google Authorization Error Error 400: redirect_uri_mismatch

Tags: c#, amazon-elastic-beanstalk, asp.net-core-webapi, google-signin, webauthenticator

I have a serious issue with my asp.net core web api, the google login works fine on localhost but when publish on the remote server in ElasticBeanstalk it's throws this error.
All the authentication process is ok on localhost. Please if someone can help to fix this issue.

Here is the exact same code that i'm using.

`public class AuthController : ControllerBase
{
const string callbackScheme = "xamarinessentials";

```
    [HttpGet("{scheme}")]
    public async Task Get([FromRoute]string scheme)
    {
        var auth = await Request.HttpContext.AuthenticateAsync(scheme);

        if (!auth.Succeeded
            || auth?.Principal == null
            || !auth.Principal.Identities.Any(id => id.IsAuthenticated)
            || string.IsNullOrEmpty(auth.Properties.GetTokenValue("access_token")))
        {
            // Not authenticated, challenge
            await Request.HttpContext.ChallengeAsync(scheme);
        }
        else
        {
            var claims = auth.Principal.Identities.FirstOrDefault()?.Claims;
            var email = string.Empty;
            email = claims?.FirstOrDefault(c => c.Type == System.Security.Claims.ClaimTypes.Email)?.Value;

            // Get parameters to send back to the callback
            var qs = new Dictionary<string, string>
            {
                { "access_token", auth.Properties.GetTokenValue("access_token") },
                { "refresh_token", auth.Properties.GetTokenValue("refresh_token") ?? string.Empty },
                { "expires", (auth.Properties.ExpiresUtc?.ToUnixTimeSeconds() ?? -1).ToString() },
                { "email", email }
            };

            // Build the result url
            var url = callbackScheme + "://#" + string.Join(
                "&",
                qs.Where(kvp => !string.IsNullOrEmpty(kvp.Value) && kvp.Value != "-1")
                .Select(kvp => $"{WebUtility.UrlEncode(kvp.Key)}={WebUtility.UrlEncode(kvp.Value)}"));

            // Redirect to final url
            Request.HttpContext.Response.Redirect(url);
        }
    }`
```

[image]
[image]

Here is the Google auth config in startup.cs or program.cs in .net 6.
[image]

This is my Google Developper consol
[image]

Comment: Have you registered the redirect uri on Google? Is the redirect uri an HTTPS endpoint?

Comment: @Llama Thank you for your quick response. But witch url exactly. I registered my custom domain like **https://mycustomdomain.com/signin-google** on Google developper console. I tried to register to default *elasticbeanstalk.com but wasn't being accepted because not https.

Comment: You should have `redirect_uri=SOMEURL` in the URL when you get redirected to Google. It's that URL that needs to be registered.

Comment: The redirect URL should be basically the same as whatever you currently have registered except for "localhost" replaced with whatever the site URL is on elasticbeanstalk. Also, you will have to use HTTPS. If you don't have that set up on elasticbeanstalk, you'll have to do that.

Comment: @JackA i've edited the question. See there is someplace where i should place the **redirecturl**.

Comment: @Llama i've edited the question please see where i should place the **redirecturl**.

Comment: `ChallengeAsync` handles that for you. It will be in your `.AddGoogleAuthentication` code, but it will only be like `/signin-google`. You need to check the URL that your browser gets directed to, as this will contain the redirect URL your server is telling Google to expect. I suggest loading Chrome's debugger, going to the Network tab, and turning "preserve log" on before going through your login flow. You want to analyse the URL your server sends the browser to after hitting the above endpoint that you provided the code for.

Comment: The redirect URL is something you have to configure in Google API console.

Comment: @Llama Please i've edited the question so you can see how i configured the AddAuthentication in startup.cs file.

Comment: @Llama i've added the Google Developper Console ScreenShot. Please have a glance and see if it's ok.

Comment: @Llama can you please UpVote back the question ?

Comment: No, because you have provided everything you could possibly provide except the most key bit of information, which is: what URL is being passed to Google? Not what are your configuration settings in ASP.NET Core or on Google, but what is the final redirect URI that is being redirected to Google that says "when the user authentication flow is done, send the credentials back to this address"?

Comment: I've even told you [how to get that information](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70795504/google-authorization-error-error-400-redirect-uri-mismatch?noredirect=1#comment125156175_70795504) easily. There's really no excuse for not including it in your question.

Comment: @Llama in the last picture i just uploaded, the url is part of the authorised url "https://ddddd.cvvvv.com/signin-google". Please check the picture.

Comment: Are you sure that's the URL being passed to Google? Have you checked that?

Comment: Well, you don't have that in the list of authorised redirect URIs.

Comment: @Llama yes i do, i said before i took the screenshot i edited the urls to anonymous urls. But i realy have the url amoung the authorised url.

Comment: And it's HTTPS in your request, and HTTPS on Google's authorised URLs list?

Comment: [My redirect URI](https://i.stack.imgur.com/gVP2g.png) - I have this exact URL, verbatim, character for character the same in my authorised redirect URIs list on Google. If yours is definitely the same in both places, and definitely HTTPS in both places, then are you sure you're using the correct clientId?

Comment: @Llama it's https in the request and https on Google too. You can check the default site on https://quitaye.mahalfial.com then after click on the **Login With Google** button.

Comment: Changing the URL to `https` takes me to the consent screen on Google successfully. That part of your configuration is correct.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/55531852/3181933 maybe

Comment: See [my screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/gVP2g.png). Same way. Chrome debugger's "Network" tab. Edge, Firefox, etc. have similar.

Comment: @Llama Thank you for all your support. I'll try that and see how it's works. I'll be back to you.

Comment: @Llama Thank you for your support. Can you please remove my real domain in the comments please. We can edit the comment and reproduce the discussion.

Comment: Long story short: ASP.NET Core determines the example.com part from the Host: header sent by the browser. It determines the http:// or https:// part using the protocol which the client has used to communicate with ASP.NET Core. It smashes that together to produce the final sign-in redirect URI. A problem if you're behind a HTTP loadbalancer or reverse proxy is that the proxy server will accept HTTPS traffic, but communicate with ASP.NET Core over HTTP. This causes (cont...)

Comment: @Llama Your suggestion actually worked. Thank you. :)

Comment: ASP.NET Core to build an HTTP URL instead of an HTTPS URL. Such load balancers and reverse proxies send a set of headers: X-Forwarded-For, X-Forwarded-Proto, and X-Forwarded-Host. We need X-Forwarded-Proto especially so that ASP.NET Core knows that the request is HTTPS. See docs. The forwarded headers middleware in ASP.NET Core should be registered before your authentication and controllers though, or else it won't populate the information at the right time.

Comment: I'm glad to hear you got it working :) I've reposted my comments without your domain included in them, as requested.

Comment: @Llama you can resume an answer. Then so i can accept it.

Comment: Your question essentially boils down to [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/55531852/3181933), so I'm not sure if it's worth adding an additional answer. Perhaps you could detail your specific solution for AWS in your own answer?

Comment: @Llama Absolutly !

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to accept the XForwardedProto

In Startup.cs or Program.cs (in .net 6)

```
public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
{
  ...
    services.Configure<ForwardedHeadersOptions>(options =>
    {
        options.ForwardedHeaders = ForwardedHeaders.XForwardedProto;
    });
   ...  
}

public void Configure(IApplicationBuilder app, IHostingEnvironment env)
{
 ...
 app.UseForwardedHeaders();
 ...
}
```

Answer (score 0):

For anyone who is struggling with this issue, i found out the the key to have everything running ok on a real server, is to make sure that HTTPS is enforced both in your app and on the server.

In your app Program.cs make sure that both the app and Google cookies are transmited over https:

```
    builder.Services.AddSession(options =>
{
    options.Cookie.SecurePolicy = CookieSecurePolicy.Always;

});


services.AddAuthentication().AddGoogle(googleOptions =>
{
    googleOptions.CorrelationCookie.SecurePolicy = CookieSecurePolicy.Always;

});
```

The issue with the redirect mismatch was really frustrating one, its seemed that nothing worked until i enforced https

```
        app.Use((context, next) =>
    {
        context.Request.Scheme = "https";
        return next(context);
    });
```

These issues usualy happen when you use a reverse proxy server (In my case Apache)
Hope that this will help out